# WPF C# insert to mysql AddWithValue

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, insert

I have an insert statement

```
 command.CommandText = "  insert into system (ziel, comment, status,art) values (@eort,@comment,@statebox,@Eart) ";
```

Behind statebox is a Combobox. Every word which can be chosen in the Combobox is created as a tablerow in my database.

the values are created here:

```
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eort",textBo3x.Text);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", textBox_Copy1.Text);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statebox", MyComboBox.Text);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Eart", MyComboBox_Copy1.Text);
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@thetime", thetime_insert.Text);
```

This works.

But I want to use the @values in the insert Statement like this:

```
 command.CommandText = "  insert into els (ziel, @statebox,comment,status,Eart) values (@eort,@thetime,@comment,@statebox,@Eart) ";
```

This gives me an mysql error.

It seems that the @values have '' at the words.
How can i delete this?

Comment: You can't use a parameter to reference a field name. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Okay, i want that the user can decide in which field he want to write the time..

Comment: If you provide your user with a predetermined list of fields between he/she can choose the field then you can safely use a form of string concatenation to insert the field to update/insert into

Comment: You may want to take a look at this. It deals with your Parameters such as `.AddWithValue` compared to `.Add`, while minimal at first, it can save you.

http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 2):

Your `INSERT` statement as pointed below is wrong. You can't simply plug-in a dynamic column in your insert statement which doesn't exists in your table schema

```
insert into system (ziel, @statebox,comment,status,Eart)
```

This can only be done in case of `SELECT` statement and doing below is perfectly alright

```
select ziel, @statebox,comment,status,Eart from `system`
```

Well, if you have your column name in variable then build your query string like

```
string query = string.Format("insert into els (ziel, {0},comment,status,Eart) values ", column_name_variable);
```

Comment: But how can i realize that a user can decide in which table row the time should be written?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a parameter to reference a field name. However, if you provide your user with a predetermined list of fields between he/she can choose then you can safely use a form of string concatenation to insert the field to update/insert into.

This means that you need to have a combobox without any editing capability but just a selection of the possible fields.

In your case, it seems that this combobox could be the one named `MyComboBox`

Thus

```
 command.CommandText = @"insert into els 
       (ziel, " + MyComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() +  
       @",comment,status,Eart) values 
       (@eort,@thetime,@comment,@statebox,@Eart)";
```

Said that consider to remove the use of AddWithValue. This shortcuts [has big drawbacks](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), in particular when you pass a string variable (Text) and expects it to correctly translate your text in a datetime value. 
Use the Add method instead converting and checking your inputs and specifying the correct datetype for the parameter.

```
DateTime dt;
if(!DateTime.TryParse(thetime_insert.Text, out dt);
    // Message, not a valid date....
else
  command.Parameters.Add("@thetime", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = dt;
```